# Showing $u^\ast$ is selfadjoint: stuck

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $u \in B(H)$. Define $(h,h') \mapsto \langle u(h), h'\rangle$. I am trying to show that $u = u^\ast$ if $\langle u(x),y\rangle = \overline{\langle y,u(x)\rangle}$ but got stuck.

I have:

$$ \|u^\ast h - uh \|^2 = \|uh\|^2 - 2 \mathrm{Re}(\langle u^\ast x,ux\rangle)+\|u^\ast h\|^2$$

and then I want to use Caucy Schwarz to get $ \|u^\ast h - uh \|^2\le (\|uh\|-\|u^\ast h\|)^2)$. But $\mathrm{Re}(\langle u^\ast x,ux\rangle) \le |\mathrm{Re}(\langle u^\ast x,ux\rangle)|$ not the other way around so I'm stuck.

> Is there anything I can do to achieve what I want?

[image]

Comment: An inner product satisfies conjugate symmetry, that is, $\langle a, b \rangle = \overline{\langle b, a \rangle}$ so I don't understand how that can imply that $u$ is self adjoint?

Comment: @copper.hat I must be misunderstanding the theorem. It's on page 52 in [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Algebras-Operator-Theory-Gerard-Murphy/dp/0125113609). I will include it in the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That $\sigma_u$ is hermitian means - apart from the sesquilinearity - that for all $x,y\in H$ we have

$$\sigma_u(y,x) = \overline{\sigma_u(x,y)}.\tag{1}$$

Expanding the definition of $\sigma_u$, $(1)$ becomes

$$\langle u(y),x\rangle = \overline{\langle u(x),y\rangle},\tag{2}$$

not $\langle u(x),y\rangle = \overline{\langle y,u(x)\rangle}$ as you wrote.

By the properties of an inner product, $(2)$ is equivalent to

$$\langle u(y),x\rangle = \langle y, u(x)\rangle.\tag{3}$$

And $(3)$ [for all $x,y\in H$] is just the definition of the self-adjointness of $u$.